# Efficiency of 2D indexing methods in Numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have seen 2D arrays indexed in two different ways in Numpy. Assuming I have an array `A`, I can type `A[0:3, 2:5]` or `A[0:3][:,2:5]`. Either way, I get the same slice of A.

I am curious why one would choose one over the other. Are there speed differences? Or is one simply more Pythonic than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first form is more pythonic and desireable, since it performs one slice operation. The second form actually slices twice.

In the first form, `A[0:3]` returns a slice that is smaller than A, then the second slice operation slices the result from the first slice one.

Comment: Interesting. I had a similar hunch, but was thrown because Numpy's website suggests the second method. [NumPy for Matlab Users](http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)

Answer (score 1):

- When you do `A[0:3,2:5]`, you're in fact doing

  ```
  A.__getitem__((slice(0,3),slice(2,5)))
  ```

  In other terms, you're calling the `__getitem__` method only once
- When you do `A[0:3][:,2:5]`, you're in fact doing

  ```
  A.__getitem__(slice(0,3)).__getitem__((slice(0,None), slice(2,5)))
  ```

  In other terms, you're (i) creating a temporary array `A[0:3]` and (ii) taking a slice on this temporary array. This is usually less efficient than the first method (direct slicing) and therefore is not recommended. [The link you refer to hasn't been updated in a while, it's likely a bug...]

Answer (score 1):

I think a good reason to use the `A[i,j]` style over the `A[i][j]` style is that it allows easy addressing of an entire row or column when slicing.

For example, `A[:,0]` will return all values in column 0, whereas `A[:][0]` will give you an index out of range error.